# channel flow with a linear velocity profile

Tags: homework-and-exercises, classical-mechanics, fluid-dynamics, bernoulli-equation

[image]

> The width of a rectangular channel with constant height $h$ perpendicular to the plane is decreaseing from $b_1$ to $b_2$. The inflow velocity is increasing linear at point 1 from $0$ to $u_1$. The velocity at point 2 is also linearly distributed above the cross section.
>
> Given: $b_1, b_2, h, u_1$ and density $\rho$
>
> (i) Calculate the volumetric flow rate $\dot{V}$
>
> (ii)  Calculate the velocities $u_{2,u}$, $u_{2,o}$ and the pressure difference $p_1-p_2$

to (i): Since the velicity profile is obviously a triangle, the solution should be $\dot{V}=0.5u_1b_1h$

to (ii): Since $\dot{V}$ is constant and the  velocity profile at point 2 is trapezial: $0.5u_1b_1h=0.5({u_{2,u}+u_{2,o})b_2h \leftrightarrow} \frac{b_1}{b_2}u_1=u_{2,u}+u_{2,o}$

Another approach (contrary to (ii) ) from me was $\dot{V}= b_2u_2+0.5b_2u_{2,o}$

Is this correct so far? How to continue?

Comment: Strange boundary conditions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Imagine a vertical $y$-axis with origin where $U=0$.

The flow rate through an infinitesimal surface element $h\mathrm{d}y$ is:

$$\mathrm{d}\dot{V}=U(y)h\mathrm{d}y$$
Where:
$$U(y)=\frac{U_1}{b_1}y$$
So that:
$$\dot{V}=\int_0^{b_1}U(y)h\mathrm{d}y=\frac{U_1}{b_1}h\int_0^{b_1}y\mathrm{d}y$$
$$\dot{V}=\frac{U_1}{2b_1}h\Big[y^2\Big]_0^{b_1}$$
$$\boxed{\dot{V}=\frac{U_1hb_1}{2}}$$
Flow of the fluid is assumed incompressible.

With a similar $y$-axis for point $2$:

$$U(y)= \frac{U_{2,o}-U_{2,u}}{b_2}y+U_{2,u}$$
$$\mathrm{d}\dot{V}=U(y)h\mathrm{d}y=\Big( \frac{U_{2,o}-U_{2,u}}{b_2}y+U_{2,u}\Big)h\mathrm{d}y$$
$$\dot{V}=\int_0^{b_2}\Big( \frac{U_{2,o}-U_{2,u}}{b_2}y+U_{2,u}\Big)h\mathrm{d}y$$
$$=h\Big( \frac{b_2(U_{2,o}-U_{2,u})}{2}+b_2U_{2,u}\Big)$$
$$\boxed{\dot{V}=\frac{(U_{2,o}+U_{2,u})hb_2}{2}}$$
And from the identity:
$$\boxed{U_{2,o}+U_{2,u}=U_1\frac{b_1}{b_2}}$$
**Pressure difference:** use Bernoulli's equation (without potential energy).
$$p_1+\frac12 \rho v_1^2=p_2+\frac12 \rho v_2^2$$
$$v_1=\frac{\dot{V}}{hb_1}=\frac{U_1}{2}$$
$$v_2=\frac{\dot{V}}{hb_2}=\frac{U_1b_1}{2b_2}$$
$$p_1-p_2=\rho\Big(\frac{U_1b_1}{2b_2}\Big)^2-\rho\Big(\frac{U_1}{2}\Big)^2$$
$$\boxed{p_1-p_2=\frac{U_1^2\rho}{4}\Bigg(\Big(\frac{b_1}{b_2}\Big)^2-1\Bigg)}$$

---

**Edit:** in response to OP's comment.

The flow velocities $U_{2,o}$ and $U_{2,u}$ can be found by assuming the *velocity gradient* ($\frac{\mathrm{d}U}{\mathrm{d}y}$) is conserved during the constriction. Mathematically this means $(1)$:

$$\frac{U_1}{b_1}=\frac{U_{2,o}-U_{2,u}}{b_2}\tag{1}$$
From above:
$$U_{2,o}+U_{2,u}=U_1\frac{b_1}{b_2}\tag{2}$$
From $(1)$:
$$U_{2,o}-U_{2,u}=\frac{U_1b_2}{b_1}\tag{3}$$
Adding $(2)$ and $(3)$:
$$\boxed{U_{2,o}=\frac12U_1\Big(\frac{b_1}{b_2}+\frac{b_2}{b_1}\Big)}\tag{4}$$
Subtracting $(3)$ from $(2)$:
$$\boxed{U_{2,u}= \frac12U_1(\frac{b_1}{b_2}-\frac{b_2}{b_1})}\tag{5}$$
So these are the velocities as in the sample solutions.

We calculate the *average flow velocities* from these:
$$v_1=\frac{\dot{V}}{hb_1}=\frac{U_1}{2}=U_{2,u}\frac{b_1b_2}{b_1^2-b_2^2}$$
$$v_2=U_1\frac{b_1}{2b_2}=U_{2,u}\frac{b_1^2}{b_1^2-b_2^2}$$
Then with Bernoulli:
$$p_1-p_2=\frac12 \rho(v_2^2-v_1^2)$$
$$p_1-p_2=\frac12 \rho U_{2,u}^2\Bigg(\frac{b_1^4-b_1^2b_2^2}{(b_1^2-b_2^2)^2}\Bigg)$$
I don't believe the sample solution provided for $p_1-p_2$ is correct.

Comment: So at point 2 $U(y)$ is: $U(y)= \frac{u_{2,o}-u_{2,u}}{b_2}y+u_{2,u}$, which leads with $\dot{V}=U(y)h$ to $\dot{V}=\frac{u_{2,o}-u_{2,u}}{b_2}hb_2+hu_{2,u}b_2$. How to get a single expression for $u_{2,o}$ and $u_{2,u}$ out of this?

Comment: Added pressure difference calculation.

Comment: The pressure differnce doesn't match with the sample solution, which is: $p_1-P-2=0.5 \rho u_{2,u}^2$. Futhermore $u_{2,u}= 0.5u_1(\frac{b_1}{b_2}-\frac{b_2}{b_1})$ and $u_{2,o}= 0.5u_1(\frac{b_1}{b_2}+\frac{b_2}{b_1})$. How to get there?

Comment: $p_1-p_2=0.5 \rho u_{2,u}^2$

Comment: I think I've got the solution. Gimme an hour.

Comment: Ok, another edit. I'm convinced the sample solution for pressure is incorrect or incomplete.